# mat-select: Hide scrollbar but enable scrolling

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

I am  creating a webpage using angular 8 with material design. I am using mat-select to dsiaplay various options. But it shows scrollbar as max-height of mat-select is 256px. I want to hide the scrollbar but enable the scrolling feature. I do not want to increase the height of mat-select-panel.
I have tried the following code but no luck so far.

trial 1::

```
    ::ng-deep {
    .mat-select-panel-wrap {
      overflow: hidden !important;
    }
    .mat-select-panel {

      overflow-y: auto !important;
    }
  }
```

trial 2::

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none !important;
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `webkit-scrollbar-track` instead of `webkit-scrollbar`

Try this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: target is chrome and safari.

Comment: @JignaRathod I have updated the code. Hope this works!